# Nice and Renice commands

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, nice, renice

I am interested in knowing what are the kernel side methods that get called when you issue the nice and renice commands? I found the set_user_nice() in the kernel side. However it's arguments are not pid and nice value, which we use when we issue the command renice(a taskstruct & nice value). Dose anyone know what functions gets called when you issue nice & renice commands?

Comment: I think renice calls set_user_nice(), because renice is for processes already running. Nice is to start a process with modified nice value..

Comment: You realize those programs are open source?  Search for GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nice` and `renice` commands invoke the `setpriority` syscall.  (You can discover this with `strace`.)

The `setpriority` function invokes the `sys_setpriority` function in the kernel (though you won't find that name in the kernel source directly; it's generated from the macro-expansion of `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(setpriority, ...)`).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes there is, but apparently `nice(1)` doesn't use it.